# Do I need to create an "app" to use the sandbox?

Tags: paypal

I used the PayPal sandbox last year when integrating a website with PayPal Pro and it was pretty straightforward. The new and improved version is confusing the heck out of me, though. Nowhere can I find an actual definition for what an "app" is (I'm not kidding, I can't find a definition anywhere) and I'm confused on what I need to do to access the sandbox.

Do I need to create an "app," or just create sandbox accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which APIs you're using. Adaptive Payments and related APIs (Adaptive Accounts, Invoicing) require a "classic" APP ID.  And REST APIs require a newer app to get credentials.

Classic APIs such as Express Checkout and Payments Pro do not require any app; merely an appropriate Business sandbox account.

So, start by figuring out which API you want to use, and then follow its documentation.

Comment: I was wanting to use Express Checkout and Payments Pro. It's confusing because the sandbox accounts are under the Applications tab on the dev site, which makes one think that an app needs to be created, but you were right that I didn't have to create an app. Thanks.

Comment: It is actually a huge mess I agree. Coz' figuring out which API you want to use is so much related to where to register, what solutions exist etc. And all the tutorials on the internet are now outdated. Not to mention that being a non-US developper, there are many `new` features I can't access ...